# For-Loops being weird

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, for-loop

For some reason, in this for loop, i is reaching 1, and causing an `index out of range` error. `Items.Count` is equal to 4, I checked that using a breakpoint, and `StockList.Count` is also equal to 4. I can't seem to figure out why i is reaching one, any idea?

```
for (int i = 0; i <= (Items.Count / 4) - 1; i++)
{
    for (int ii = 0;ii <= Program.StockList.Count - 1;i++)
    {
        if (Items[(i * 4) + 3] == Program.StockList[ii].ID) //Crash here
        {
            MessageBox.Show(Program.StockList[ii].Name + " Match!");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You are incrementing `i` in your second for loop. I hate it when that happens.

Comment: Picking good variable names is 90% of that battle, `i` and `ii` are not good names.

Comment: Just to add to the variable naming battle, a good example for using loops is it use i for the first dimension, j for the second and k for a third.

Answer (score 5):

This (the second loop):

```
for (int ii = 0;ii <= Program.StockList.Count - 1;i++)
```

Should be this:

```
for (int ii = 0;ii <= Program.StockList.Count - 1;ii++)
```

I'm sure it's hard to spot the difference here, so no surprise it was even harder in your code. Consider using `j` for the inner loop, and partitioning your code into smaller functions to avoid such mistakes.

Also as noted by [kenny](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3225/kenny) in the comments below, you can replace the second loop with a `foreach` loop:

```
foreach (var stock in Program.StockList)
{
    if (Items[(i * 4) + 3] == stock.ID)
    {
        //...
    }
}
```

Comment: Ahh, that was it. In the previous languages I've used, I didn't have to do the i++ thing, so I'll have to pay attention to that in nested loops. Thanks!

Comment: @Nathan are you aware of foreach to iterate through collections?